# Increase clickable area of slots behind Fullcalendar event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fullcalendar

In week view of Fullcalendar.js, there is a small space to the right of the rightmost event (in each day/overlapping), so that the slots this event occupies may remain clickable. However, the space is pretty small by default. I need to make it bigger.

I inspected every element of the tables that conform a Fullcalendar (currently using version 2.5.0), but I can't seem to find the place where the width of this space is set. I'm beginning to think it's calculated from the events' width, but I'm uncertain.

Is there any way to increase this space in week view?

[image: Example]

**EDIT:**

The only provided answer does not work as intended because it adds some space to the right of ALL overlapping events (If two or more events overlap, then the space is added between the overlapping events, and not just to the rightmost event, as desired.)

**EDIT:**
There is now an officially accepted answer that seems to be working.

Comment: You are talking about the `week` view right? because in the `day` view, all events are stretched. In the `week` view, the width is split between the weekdays (Sunday to Saturday). you can't make an event have more width because that would essentially make it appear in the next day as well, which I am not sure if you want to happen. If you try to increase the width of each day column, it could create inconsistencies with other days or make the fullCalendar have a horizontal scrollbar.... so maybe tell us more about your DESIRED behaviour and maybe a screenshot of how it should be.

Comment: @Aziz Sorry, I thought the picture was clarifying enough. To the right of the 9-9.30 event there is a small space so I can click the 9-9.15 slot or the 9.15-9.30 slot. I need to make this space bigger, only in week view (day view has an acceptable space to click the slot)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is quite old but maybe it helps someone:
You can just set the event container margin

```
.fc-ltr .fc-time-grid .fc-event-container {
    margin: 0 5.0% 0 2px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
eventAfterRender: function( event, element, view ) { 
    var width = $(element).width();
    width = width - ( width / 3); // Less whatever you want
    // Set the new width
    $(element).css('width', width + 'px');
}
```

This works for me.

Comment: I just want to increase the space of the rightmost event, doesn't this increase the space of all events (consider the case of two or more overlapping events)?

Comment: Thanks anyways, but this is not what I'm looking for.